# Google Sheets monthly sum code optimization

Tags: optimization, google-sheets

Good day everybody, we are making a spreadsheets for incoming cash monitoring, and I feel like the method I used to achieve the monthly sum is possibly the worst.

So I was wondering if some of you guys have a shorter solution

```
=SUM(FILTER('Dashboard'!D2:D;'Dashboard'!E2:E="Incoming";'Dashboard'!C2:C>=DATE(text(today()-text(today();"dd");"yyyy");(text(today()-text(today();"dd");"mm"));(text(today()-text(today();"dd");"dd")));'Dashboard'!C2:C<=DATE(text(today();"yyyy");(text(today();"mm"));(text(today();"dd")))))
```

So since this looks like a cluster**** of code, i will try to annotate it:

```
=SUM(FILTER('Dashboard'!D2:D;'Dashboard'!E2:E="Incoming"
```

Sort by only the incoming cash and not outgoing

```
;Dashboard'!C2:C>=DATE(text(today()-text(today();"dd");"yyyy");(text(today()-text(today();"dd");"mm"));(text(today()-text(today();"dd");"dd")));'Dashboard'!C2:C<=DATE(text(today();"yyyy");(text(today();"mm"));(text(today();"dd")))
```

The range is from 1'st day of the month to todays date.

Method: Get todays date, and subtract todays date, to get the first day of the month.

Which isn't even a true monthly sum, rather than up to current day sum.

I'm really sorry but due to company policy I cant link the file itself, but the sheet is rather simple
The columns are:

Date, Sum, "Incoming/Outgoing", "Cash/Credit"

I also have a weekly sum, but I feel like that formula is somewhat decent

```
=query(filter('Dashboard'!C2:D;'Dashboard'!E2:E="Incoming";weeknum('Dashboard'!C2:C;1)=weeknum(today();1));"Select Sum (Col2) label Sum(Col2)''";-1)
```

Comment: I can see the formulas that you have, but I'm not sure what your question is. Do all of the formulas work as intended?

Comment: You're right, sorry, edited the question. They work as intended, but I was wondering if there is a better solution to the question

Comment: Stack Overflow is for questions to fix code that isn't working, this question would be better suited to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). See [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/238656) answer on Meta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to format the date to 'yyyy-mm-dd'. You can use EndOfMONTH to get the last day of last month.

```
=SUM(FILTER('Dashboard'!D2:D;'Dashboard'!E2:E="Incoming";'Dashboard'!C2:C>EOMONTH(TODAY(),-1);'Dashboard'!C2:C<=TODAY())
```